# How to get MAC address using sys/unix in Go

Tags: linux, go, system-calls

I am writing a sample program to get a MAC address using sys/unix package on Ubuntu22.04 docker container.

What I am doing is to call `unix.IoctlIfreq(soc, unix.SIOCGIFHWADDR, ifr)` and get the bytes in `ifr`. But `Ifreq` struct has only `Uint32()` and `Uint16()` as exported methods and MAC Address has 6 bytes length.

What is a good way to get a MAC address?
(I can find many examples of getting a MAC address with syscall package but cannot find the way with sys/unix.)

Comment: What's wrong with using `net.Interfaces()` from the standard library?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! There is nothing wrong with net library :) I just wanted to use sys library for learning purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use the more generic `net` package

Use [Interfaces](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Interfaces) to get list of network interfaces.

> func Interfaces() ([]Interface, error)

```
type Interface struct {
    Index        int          // positive integer that starts at one, zero is never used
    MTU          int          // maximum transmission unit
    Name         string       // e.g., "en0", "lo0", "eth0.100"
    HardwareAddr HardwareAddr // IEEE MAC-48, EUI-48 and EUI-64 form
    Flags        Flags        // e.g., FlagUp, FlagLoopback, FlagMulticast
}
```

Then use [HardwareAddr](https://pkg.go.dev/net#HardwareAddr) to get physical hardware address.

> func (a HardwareAddr) String() string